# How to get the access token automatically in facebook

Tags: facebook, r, api, oauth, web-scraping

I'm trying to make some sort of dashboard of my facebook in R. Some basic stuff. I would like to automate the script so that it can periodically update itself. I use knitr and task manager to produce the dashboard, which works well.

I use the facebook code of [romainfrancois' blog](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2012/01/15/Crawling-facebook-with-R) to get the facebook data:

```
facebook <-  function( path = "me", access_token = token, options){
  if( !missing(options) ){
    options <- sprintf( "?%s", paste( names(options), "=", unlist(options), collapse = "&", sep = "" ) )
  } else {
    options <- ""
  }
  url <- sprintf( "https://graph.facebook.com/%s%s&access_token=%s", path, options, access_token )
  # print(url)
  data <- getURL( url )
  fromJSON( data )
}
```

The only problem is to get the access token automatically.

I tried to webscrape the token of the webpage:

```
library(RCurl)
FBdevPage<-browseURL("http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer")
FBdevPage[21]
```

It should be on line 21, according to the source code of the page. However, in R it only shows a backslash. Does someone had any ideas to get the access token? Or otherwise, store the procedure, while it allows to retrieve the data each time?

Comment: Other than the actual [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) flows that facebook provides, you mean?

Comment: I read something about the extended access tokens which can be requested with 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    fb_exchange_token=SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens)

However, I don't know how to do this with Graph API. The app id and app secret must be provided, which I do not have.